# Can these locks be rekeyed to the same key?

Tags: lock

I have 3 external doors on my house. Each has a different key. Two are Schlage sets and one is a Norwalk. The Norwalk blank says AR1 on it, and the Schlages are the standard version.

The Norwalk is what I'm most concerned about. It looks vintage, and is a sash lock. Turning the key operates both the deadlock as well as the latch. I don't know if these two systems can be made to work with the same blanks.

I would like to do this myself, but am currently more curious if it is possible at all.

Is there a way to have all the locks share a common key?

[image: lock]
 [image: lock]
 [image: lock]
 [image: keys]

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible, or whether you can do it yourself? Because the answer to the former question is pretty clear: "Yes; call a locksmith." :)

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Will the Schlage key fit in the Norwalk? If so the next question is it a 5 pin or 7 pin? In otherwords are both keys the same length? The shank length of the keys, Norwalk and Schlage. If this criteria is met the answer is yes. You can also swap out the Norwalk tumbler only to a Schlage, no need to change the whole lock. Tumbler length and style of the tang on the back of the tumbler are important here when you do a swap out.

Comment: The Norwalk key is 2-3mm longer than the schlage, but the schlage does not go in because the groves along the sides of the key are different. Both appear to be 5 pin keys.

Comment: The true question is: can I purchase new lock cylinders  that match, for the given three locks?

Comment: @Bryce, that should not be a problem. @ John, just clarify, with that last bit of info, there is no way to key the Norwalk alike with the Schlage using the existing tumbler, it must be replaced with a Schlage or even Baldwin tumbler, which has a Schlage keyway. Yes you can still do it yourself but you must remove the tumbler, take it to the locksmith and have it matched up. This will only save you a house call charge. The screws to remove the lock are hidden behind the latch plate most of the time. Sometimes there are visible holes through the latch plate to access the set screws for the lock

Comment: I forgot to add, just the Norwalk tumbler needs to be swapped out, not all three. But the locksmith will need to know the key that it will be change too as well otherwise he may give you a 7 pin Schlage tumbler

Comment: @Jack Why not make this an answer?

Comment: Great. @Jack, if you want to move your thoughts to an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that last bit of info, there is no way to key the Norwalk alike with the Schlage using the existing tumbler, it must be replaced with a Schlage or even Baldwin tumbler, which has a Schlage keyway. Yes you can still do it yourself but you must remove the tumbler, take it to the locksmith and have it matched up. This will only save you a house call charge. The screws to remove the lock are hidden behind the latch plate most of the time. Sometimes there are visible holes through the latch plate to access the set screws for the lock. Just the Norwalk tumbler needs to be swapped out, not all three. But the locksmith will need to know the key that it will be change too as well otherwise he may give you a 7 pin Schlage tumbler.